Executive ./bin/start-cluster.sh is giving update#setState idle error
I am facing struggle with starting Flink,it is showing up with update#setState idle and few other commands and leading to opening the code in vscode and displaying starting cluster commands. how to solve it?
I tried starting my Flink server.
